# How to search JSON array in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

Let's say I have a JSON column named **data** in some MySQL table, and this column is a single *array*. So, for example, data may contain:

> [1,2,3,4,5]

Now I want to select all rows which have a data column where one of its array elements is greater than 2. Is this possible?

I tried the following, but seems it is always *true* regardless of the values in the array:

```
SELECT * from my_table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$[*]') > 2;
```

Comment: You can search json arrays in postgresql, normally as other fields, in mysql you have to search using mysql functions that you can find here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find a way to search json array using these functions

Comment: Din you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Please did you find a solution to this as i'm stucked as well..
im trying to search [{"id":1}, {"id":2}]. To search where e.g id = 1 or so

Comment: No I didn't find a solution

Comment: i need this :((

Answer (score 117):

You may search an array of integers as follows:

```
  JSON_CONTAINS('[1,2,3,4,5]','7','$') Returns: 0
  JSON_CONTAINS('[1,2,3,4,5]','1','$') Returns: 1
```

You may search an array of strings as follows:

```
  JSON_CONTAINS('["a","2","c","4","x"]','"x"','$') Returns: 1
  JSON_CONTAINS('["1","2","3","4","5"]','"7"','$') Returns: 0
```

Note: JSON_CONTAINS returns either 1 or 0

In your case you may search using a query like so:

```
SELECT * from my_table
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, '2', '$');
```

Comment: Omitting the `'$'` is also okay.

Comment: what my SQL version supports that?

Comment: Starting with MySQL 5.7

Comment: That does not answer the question at all, we need all values which is greater than 2 not which equals 2

Comment: ¿How to resolve this?

Comment: depending on your MySQL server you might have to cast the item you search for to a json. for example: `JSON_CONTAINS('[1,2,3,4,5]',CAST(7 as json))`.

Comment: thanks @MNU-548 . it worked but i had to add double quote syntax when i pass column as first parameter to JSON_CONTAINS

Answer (score 32):

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH('["1","2","3","4","5"]', 'one', "2") is not null
```

is true

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH('["1","2","3","4","5"]', 'one', "6") is not null
```

is false

Comment: why i cannot do like this? `SELECT JSON_SEARCH('[1,2,3,4,5]', 'one', 1) is not null`

Comment: @Bobby https://stackoverflow.com/a/46719070/12538152

Answer (score 17):

[Since MySQL 8](https://mysqlserverteam.com/whats-new-in-mysql-8-0-generally-available/) there is a new function called [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html).

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT, data JSON);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES 
  (1, "[1,2,3,4,5]"), 
  (2, "[0,1,2]"), 
  (3, "[3,4,-10]"), 
  (4, "[-1,-2,0]");

SELECT DISTINCT my_table.* 
FROM my_table, JSON_TABLE(data, "$[*]" COLUMNS(nr INT PATH '$')) as ids 
WHERE ids.nr > 2;

+------+-----------------+
| id   | data            |
+------+-----------------+
|    1 | [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] |
|    3 | [3, 4, -10]     |
+------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes, this query work for me. @Loai you can use this.

Comment: Even tho I copied the create table, insert table and then tried to query the select, it failed at the final select

Comment: Works in MariaDB since v10.6. Although DISTINCT is ambiguous.

Answer (score 13):

I use a combination of JSON_EXTRACT and JSON_CONTAINS (MariaDB):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(json_field, '$[*].id'), 11, '$');
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if we found the solution.
I found with MariaDB a way, to search path in a array. For example, in array `[{"id":1}, {"id":2}]`, I want find path with id equal to 2.

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH('name_field', 'one', 2, null, '$[*].id')
FROM name_table
```

The result is:

```
"$[1].id"
```

The asterisk indicate searching the entire array

Comment: This worked in MySQL as well. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: An explanation of what 'one', 2, null do would be useful

Comment: @james Or a link to the doc: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_search/

Answer (score 3):

This example works for me with mysql `5.7` above

```sql
SET @j = '{"a": [ "8428341ffffffff", "8428343ffffffff", "8428345ffffffff", "8428347ffffffff","8428349ffffffff", "842834bffffffff", "842834dffffffff"], "b": 2, "c": {"d": 4}}';
select JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(@j , '$.a'),'"8428341ffffffff"','$') => returns 1
```

notice about `"` around search keyword, `'"8428341ffffffff"'`

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is to deal with the problem as string matching. Convert the JSON to string and match.

Or you can use [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html).

Comment: I'm not sure that string matching will work as I want to compare for greater than not only equality, same goes for json_contains, it search for exact contain, not compare functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @doc = '[{"SongLabels": [{"SongLabelId": "111", "SongLabelName": "Funk"}, {"SongLabelId": "222", "SongLabelName": "RnB"}], "SongLabelCategoryId": "test11", "SongLabelCategoryName": "曲风"}]';
SELECT *,  JSON_SEARCH(@doc, 'one', '%un%', null, '$[*].SongLabels[*].SongLabelName')FROM t_music_song_label_relation;
```

result: "$[0].SongLabels[0].SongLabelName"

```
SELECT song_label_content->'$[*].SongLabels[*].SongLabelName' FROM t_music_song_label_relation;
```

result: ["Funk", "RnB"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON extract to search and select data

```
SELECT data, data->"$.id" as selectdata
FROM table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.id") = '123'
#ORDER BY c->"$.name";
limit 10 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem, search via function

```
create function searchGT(threshold int, d JSON)
returns int
    begin
        set @i = 0;
        while @i < json_length(d) do
            if json_extract(d, CONCAT('$[', @i, ']')) > threshold then
                return json_extract(d, CONCAT('$[', @i, ']'));
            end if;
            set @i = @i + 1;
        end while;
        return null;
    end;

select searchGT(3, CAST('[1,10,20]' AS JSON));
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be possible with to `JSON_TABLE` function. It's available in mysql version 8.0 or mariadb version 10.6.

With this test setup

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytable
WITH data(a,json) AS (VALUES ('a','[1]'),
                             ('b','[1,2]'),
                             ('c','[1,2,3]'),
                             ('d','[1,2,3,4]'))
SELECT * from data;
```

we get the following table

```
+---+-----------+
| a | json      |
+---+-----------+
| a | [1]       |
| b | [1,2]     |
| c | [1,2,3]   |
| d | [1,2,3,4] |
+---+-----------+
```

It's possible to select every row from mytable wich has a value greater than 2 in the json array with this query.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE TRUE IN (SELECT val > 2
               FROM JSON_TABLE(json,'$[*]'
                            columns (val INT(1) path '$')
                    ) as json
              )
```

Returns:

```
+---+-----------+
| a | json      |
+---+-----------+
| c | [1,2,3]   |
| d | [1,2,3,4] |
+---+-----------+
```