# MYSQL Triggers: JSON_SEARCH an integer value in a json array of integers

Tags: mysql, json, triggers

I am looking to use json_search to get the array path that corresponds to a value.

I have tried and this works:

```
SET @j = '["3", "2", "1"]';
SELECT json_search(@j, 'one', '2');
```

returns $[1];

I have tried and this doesn't work: (How do I make this work?)

```
SET @j = '[3, 2, 1]';
SELECT json_search(@j, 'one', 2);
```

returns null;

Basically I want to store @j as an integer array instead of a string array for indexing purposes. Is there any way I can change the integer array into a string array for comparison if there is no way for json_search to work with integers?

Comment: Looks like this bug still has not been fixed: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79316

Comment: oh this is a bug :(, looks like I will have to change the data type back to varchar huh

Answer (score 9):

It is by design, although I can not agree with mySQL team. This should be implemented.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233 [closed]

> The specification at https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7909 says:
>   "This function returns path(s) to the given string. The returned
>   path(s) identify object members or array slots which are character
>   strings."
>
> So it seems that the intention of this function was to search for
>   strings. The documentation should be updated to clarify that the
>   function is for searching for string scalars, not for scalars in
>   general.

Comment: This is really confusing because `json_array(1,2,3)` returns `[1, 2, 3]` instead of `["1", "2", "3"]` so one would naturally think json_search also works for integer arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a workaround method, which is to CONCAT the string and cast it back to JSON and update the table. It's not the most elegant way, so if you guys have any suggestion, please let me know! :)

```
BEGIN
DECLARE var1 INT default -2; //offsets
DECLARE var2 INT default 2; //offsets
SELECT StatusID into @statusList FROM UserStatusesIndex;
SET @statusID_to_remove = OLD.StatusID;
SET @startIndex = INSTR(@statusList, @statusID_to_remove);
SET @charLength = CHAR_LENGTH(@statusID_to_remove);

IF @startIndex <= 2 THEN SET var1=-1, var2=2; //If its the first index
ELSEIF (CHAR_LENGTH(@statusList) - @startIndex <= 2) THEN SET var1=-3, var2=0;  //If its the last index
ELSE SET var1=-2, var2=2;
END IF;

SET @newJson=CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@statusList, 1, @startIndex+var1), SUBSTR(@statusList, @startIndex + @charLength+var2, CHAR_LENGTH(@statusList) - @startIndex - @charLength+2)) as JSON);
UPDATE UserStatusesIndex SET StatusID=@newJson WHERE StatusCreator=OLD.StatusCreator;
END
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could prefix your JSON_ARRAY of INTEGERs with an alpha character like this:

```
SET @trailers := JSON_ARRAY(
't9'
,'t10'
,'t11'
,'t12'
,'t13'
,'t14'
);
```

Then, when you use it to locate the associated ids with JSON_SEARCH, you can use CONCAT to prefix the id in your table with the same value like this:

```
select * from trailers.trailer t
where 
JSON_SEARCH(@open_trailers, 'one', concat('t', t.trailer_id )) IS NOT NULL
;
```

That should work, but be aware of potential performance issues that may arise.

Best of luck!

Answer (score -2):

This seems to work:

```
SET @j = '[3, 2, 1]';
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@j, '3', '$');
```

Comment: Always return contains or not contains, and not the path, nowhere related to the question asked