# Get data from database with WHERE clause from JSON Array in mySQL or Laravel

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column `ordersdetail` with type `JSON` in my mysql table `orderAnalysis` with below example.

## first row

```
{ "id": 123, "items": [ { "id": 1623364501551, "product_id": 11931258628 }, { "id": 1623364534319, "product_id": 11931258630 }] }
```

## second row

```
{ "id": 124, "items": [ { "id": 1623364501552, "product_id": 11931258629 },  { "id": 1623364534320, "product_id": 11931258632 }] }
```

I want to get row data if any `product_id` matched with given id from array of items. I have done R&D for it and got some solutions and when I tried that solutions none of thems didn't worked in my case.

I am tried using these queries as below:-

```
#first query 
SELECT ordersdetail FROM `orderAnalysis` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(ordersdetail->>'$.items[*].product_id', 'one', 11931258628)

#second query 
SELECT ordersdetail FROM `orderAnalysis` WHERE ordersdetail->"$.items[*].product_id" = 11931258628

#third query 
SELECT ordersdetail FROM `orderAnalysis` WHERE json_extract(ordersdetail, '$.items[*].product_id') = 11931258628
```

But these queries not helped me to get result. I want `first row` as output in result. Please help me. 
Thanx in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL Triggers: JSON\_SEARCH an integer value in a json array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356672/mysql-triggers-json-search-an-integer-value-in-a-json-array-of-integers)

Comment: Unfortunately this is a non-feature in MySQL; `JSON_SEARCH` only works on string values. See the duplicate...