# In MySQL, json_search fail with integer element in json_array

Tags: mysql

I have a json_array [1, 2, 3, 3, 3], and I want to find out where how many the element '3' is.

For example,

```
json_search('[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]', 'all', 3) return null;
json_search('["1", "2", "3", "3", "3"]', 'all', '3') return ["$[2]", "$[3]", "$[4]"];
```

Therefore,

```
json_length(json_search('[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]', 'all', 3)) return null;
```

I want to 3

I’ve been looking all day, but I don’t know the solution and ask for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL Triggers: JSON\_SEARCH an integer value in a json array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356672/mysql-triggers-json-search-an-integer-value-in-a-json-array-of-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here, assuming you have just a single top level array of JSON integers, would be to use a regex replacement trick to count the number of 3's:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '[1, 2, 3, 3, 3]' AS array
)

SELECT
    LENGTH(array) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(array, '\\b3\\b', '')) AS num_3
FROM yourTable;
```

This returns 3 as the length, which is correct.

Comment: I use mysql version 5.7, so I couldn't use the method you told, but I got a big idea and solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @serverwizard Thanks for the vote, but if your answer is very different than what I posted, but it worked, you should consider answering your own question (yes--you can actually do this).