# Select all rows where key in JSON key value array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mysql-json

Okay, so I just found out that you can save and select on the JSON data type in MySQL.

I tried to follow [user2458995](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249828/how-to-search-json-array-in-mysql)'s answer to a similar question as mine, (The difference is mine is with a key and the value is an array) I copied his exact code, created the table, put in the data from his insert SQL and tried his select, which gave me an error.

I modified the table here to show a sample of how the data will be stored in my example.

Basically I have this setup

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT, data JSON);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, '{"hashtags": ["html", "php", "javascript"], "categories": [2,5,6]}'), (2, '{"hashtags": ["css", "jquery", "html"], "categories": [2,5,6]}')
```

If I want to select all the hashtags I can do it like this

```
SELECT data->>"$.hashtags" FROM my_table
```

But how do I select data like a where in?

I imagined something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE 'html' IN (data->>"$.hashtags")
```

It does execute, but it returns no rows.
I also tried several other suggested ways but I can't get anything to work

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS('html', '$.hashtags')
```

I thought this would be a really neat approach, but would it be smarter to just store each category/hashtag in a unique row with an FK id?

I hope someone can help me out here :)

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.7.27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adress this with [`JSON_SEARCH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search), available in MySQL 5.7:

```
select *
from `my_table` 
where json_search(data, 'one', 'html', null, '$.hashtags[*]') is not null
```

Explanation:

```
json_search(
    data,            -- json document to search
    'one',           -- the search terminates after the first match 
    'html',          -- search string argument
    null,            -- escape character: none
    '$.hashtags[*]'  -- path to search: the json array under attribyte 'hashtag'
)
```

**[Demo on MySQL 5.7 DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n6LxEN21rsk3oXM3UbJaQD/0)**:

```
select 
    t.*,
    json_search(data, 'one', 'html', null, '$.hashtags[*]') matched_path
from `my_table` t 
where json_search(data, 'one', 'html', null, '$.hashtags[*]') is not null;

| id  | data                                                                 | matched_path    |
| --- | -------------------------------------------------------------------- | --------------- |
| 1   | {"hashtags": ["html", "php", "javascript"], "categories": [2, 5, 6]} | "$.hashtags[0]" |
| 2   | {"hashtags": ["css", "jquery", "html"], "categories": [2, 5, 6]}     | "$.hashtags[2]" |
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! :) should I look into upgrading to MySQL version 8? Also what are your thoughts, is it a bad way to store the data for hashtags and categories, instead of single rows with FK ids:)?

Comment: Welcome @iiiml0sto1! Glad that it worked out for you.

Comment: is there a way I can search for multiple values? like the where in, if I etch want all the results where etc 'html' and 'php' are presented?