# Select query for rows which contains specific values within a json array?

Tags: mysql, json

I have this table currently

```
ID | Seller_Name | Seller_Non_Working_Day
1 | Seller A | [1,7]
2 | Seller B | [1]
3 | Seller C | []
4 | Seller D | [1,7]
```

I'm trying to extract seller who are not working on Sundays only, aka with [1] in the Seller_Non_Working_Day. This field is a JSON type.

This is my query, and I'm not getting any response :(

```
select * from table_name
where Seller_Non_Working_Day IN ('[1]')
```

Able to assist pls?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249828/how-to-search-json-array-in-mysql

Comment: *I'm trying to extract seller who are not working on Sundays only, aka with [1] in the Seller_Non_Working_Day.* I.e. the outpout must contain only the row with `ID = 2`? if so use direct compare `WHERE Seller_Non_Working_Day = '[1]'`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL **JSON_OVERLAPS** function compares two doc_path or arrays.It returns 0 if value do not match and 1 if it does.

```
JSON_OVERLAPS(doc_path1, doc_path2)
```

For your query, I have created a second array with one value [1] i.e. for Sunday. This will compare all records and return 0 and 1.Query result for sellers working on Sundays will return 1. To eliminate non-required records which are returning 1, I have added a **WHERE** clause. Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE JSON_OVERLAPS(Seller_Non_Working_Day , '[1]') != 1 ;
```

There is another function **JSON_CONTAINS** which will list all records containing the specific value e.g. [1] at any position within JSON array. The syntax for JSON_CONTAINS is

```
JSON_CONTAINS(target, candidate[, path])

target is a specific field. Here it would be Seller_Non_Working_Day
candidate is a specific value to find. Here it would be [1]
Path is any specific array location which is optional.
```

One can use below query to fetch all sellers which are working on Sundays.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(Seller_Non_Working_Day , '[1]');
```

Comment: OP needs *extract seller who are not working on Sundays **only*** whereas your query returns the rows regardless of whether there are other values.

Comment: Hi when i tried the second option:
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(Seller_Non_Working_Day , '[1]');

It returns me records with [1] and also [1,7].
I want only the records with [1] only