# how to check if array contains specific string in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to check if column contains string for example i have the following arrays;

```
['1','2']
['1']
['1','2','3']
```

I need to make an sql query to find if any of the arrays contains for example 1
so far i tried to use 'like' and 'in' but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: why are you using sql?  the database doesn't have any arrays in it, so they must be in your code.  if you are actually wanting to look in a database column, show us what the data looks like in the database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search JSON array in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249828/how-to-search-json-array-in-mysql)

Comment: MySQL doesn't have arrays, so your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what your table or column names are but if those examples represent a single column data, like clause  should be working;

```
  select * from TABLE where COLUMN like '%1%'
```

Comment: this wont find ['1','2']

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the index of the array where you are checking

```
    select * from TABLE where COLUMN[1] like '%1%'
```

Comment: Sql doesn't support arrays so `column[1]` wont work.