# How to select data from array stored as string in table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My team has stored array data as a string in MySQL like below

```
["1","2","22","11"]
```

How can we select data from the table where the column contains a certain branch number.

Example of table

```
sno | Name | Branch 
1.  | Tom. | ["1","2","22"]
2.  | Tim. | ["1","2"]
```

Can you suggest a query to select all rows containing branch 2?

We tried using `FIND_IN_SET()` but that is not working as the double quotes and square brackets are also a part of string.

Comment: If you mean the column is type `json` this thread has a few suggestions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249828/how-to-search-json-array-in-mysql such as JSON_TABLE or JSON_CONTAINS.  Not sure which (if any) is the best option performance wise .  See example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b5ab9f506614e08bbb802d0946bfda2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like:

```
select *
from mytable
where Branch like '%"2"%'
```

Comment: Well if you're going to be *logical* about it ... (-;